# Forgotten RAR password recovery

Tags: passwords, recovery, rar

Hi everyone who can help me.
I have made RAR file with password on 200 and after so long time i forgot password, i tryed many combinations, try letters and numbers i think i can be in password, nothing, with special sowfware nothing to, can someone help me to get somehow recover this password?

Tryed brute-force with some apps like: 'Passper for RAR', 'PassFab for RAR', 'iSumsoft RAR Password Refixer', etc.
Tryed dictionaries, but ther is pass what i made, not like in some dictionaries.
Tryed letter what can be in password in different combinations.
Even tryed to crate php based pasword guessing by the given symbols and all possible combinations.

Answer (score 0):

If you forgot your password, save for brute forcing it, you're done for. [RAR uses AES 256 encryption](https://www.win-rar.com/encryption-faq.html) to encrypt archives, not to mention you can't just recover the password from information stored within the archive (since it only stores a hash to check if the password is correct), *and* the fact that every portion of a file inside a protected archive is encrypted.

Comment: Updated wording, I re-read it and it made no sense compared to what I wanted to say.